# How to get the column values of a Dataframe into another dataframe as a new column after matching the values in columns that both dataframes have?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in a DataFrame and storing it with values stored in a different dataframe by first comparing the values of columns that both dataframes have. For example:

```
df1 >>> 

| name | team | week |  dates     | interceptions |  pass_yds |  rating  |
| ---- | ---- | -----| ---------- | ------------- | --------- | -------- |
| maho |  KC  |   1  | 2020-09-10 |      0        |    300    |    105   |
| went | PHI  |   1  | 2020-09-13 |      2        |    225    |    74    |
| lock | DEN  |   1  | 2020-09-14 |      0        |    150    |    89    |             
| dris | DEN  |   2  | 2020-09-20 |      1        |    220    |    95    |
| went | PHI  |   2  | 2020-09-20 |      2        |    250    |    64    |
| maho |  KC  |   2  | 2020-09-21 |      1        |    245    |    101   |
```

```
df2 >>>

| name | team | week | catches | rec_yds | rec_tds |
| ---- | ---- | -----| ------- | ------- | ------- |
| ertz | PHI  |   1  |    5    |   58    |    1    |
| fant | DEN  |   2  |    6    |   79    |    0    |
| kelc |  KC  |   2  |    8    |   105   |    1    |
| fant | DEN  |   1  |    3    |   29    |    0    |
| kelc |  KC  |   1  |    6    |   71    |    1    |
| ertz | PHI  |   2  |    7    |   91    |    2    |
| goed | PHI  |   2  |    2    |   15    |    0    |
```

I want to create a `dates` column in df2 with the values of the dates stored in the `dates` column in df1 after matching the teams and the weeks columns. After the matching, df2 in this example should look something like this:

```
df2 >>>

| name | team | week | catches | rec_yds | rec_tds |  dates     | 
| ---- | ---- | -----| ------- | ------- | ------- | ---------- |
| ertz | PHI  |   1  |    5    |    58   |    1    | 2020-09-13 |
| fant | DEN  |   2  |    6    |    79   |    0    | 2020-09-20 |
| kelc |  KC  |   2  |    8    |    105  |    1    | 2020-09-20 |
| fant | DEN  |   1  |    3    |    29   |    0    | 2020-09-14 |
| kelc |  KC  |   1  |    6    |    71   |    1    | 2020-09-10 |
| ertz | PHI  |   2  |    7    |    91   |    2    | 2020-09-20 |
| goed | PHI  |   2  |    2    |    15   |    0    | 2020-09-20 |
```

I'm looking for an optimal solution. I've already tried nested for loops and comparing the `week` and `team` columns from both dataframes together but that hasn't worked. At this point I'm all out of ideas. Please help!

Disclaimer: The actual DataFrames I'm working with are a lot larger. They have a lot more rows, columns, and values (i.e. a lot more teams in the `team` columns, a lot more dates in the `dates` columns, and a lot more weeks in the `week` columns)

Comment: Have you tried: `df2.merge(df1)` ? - see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: @JonClements I have but it's a bit complicated. For the dataframes I'm actually working with, both have a `team` column,  a `week` column, and a few other columns but the rest of the columns in both dataframes are completely different. So with that, I'm not sure how I can use `merge`. I've already tried but I kept getting errors.

Comment: It'd be handy if you could [edit] to include that information in a bit more detail...

Comment: @JonClements I just finished the edit. Hopefully now it's clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So what about `df2.merge(df1[['team', 'week', 'dates']])` ?

Comment: @JonClements it worked. Thank you very much!